# In a Kafka key/value record should the key be present in value?

Tags: apache-kafka

I am wondering what the best practises are designing key/value records in Kafka.
Should the key always be present in the value of the record and if yes/no what's the reason?

Tring to design a solid solution for future purposes kafka streaming pipeline.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: It Depends.

Majority of the time I recon it would but it depends on what is stored in the topic.
For example if your topic stores orders, and the Key is the orderId, and the value contains the complete order, it would make sense that the value will also contain the key.
On the other hand if the topic is a result of some aggregation (e.g. count of orders per day) it would not have the orderId.

Comment: Also for tombstone events, the entire value is null, so wouldn't have the key/ID